Not Receiving Webhooks from whatsapp
I've gone through the whole flow of whatsapp business api with embedded signup. I'm facing two issues.

I've gone through the embed signup step and getting the right responses, access tokens, etc. The issue I am having is that after subscribing to a webhook, any messages sent to the registered phone number is not triggering the whatsapp webhook I've built on my server. I do see the log for the verification being checked to make sure it is available but not getting any message events.

Randomly after experiencing the above issue, the registered phone number stopped working and now when trying with new numbers, it the whatsapp business app keeps saying try again in one hour. how do i fix this?


Thanks for any help in advance!
